Conditional Expectation and regular conditional probability
Is it true in general that:
$$E(g(X,Y)|Y)(\omega) = \int_Rg(x,Y(\omega)) P_{X|Y}(dx,\omega) \qquad a.s.P \tag{1}$$
Where $g$ is some borel measurable function, $X,Y$ are random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$, and $P_{X|Y}$ is a regular conditional distribution such that for each fixed borel set $B$, we have that:
$$\int_\Omega 1_{Y^{-1}(A)}(\omega )P_{X|Y}(B,\omega)P(d\omega) = P(\{X\in B\}\cap\{Y\in A\}) \qquad \text{for all borel $A$}$$
I know that  $E(h(X)|Y)(\omega) = \int_Rh(x) P_{X|Y}(dx,\omega)\quad a.s.P$ holds but I not sure if (1) holds.
I know how to prove that $\int_Rg(x,Y(\omega)) P_{X|Y}(dx,\omega)$ is $\sigma(Y)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}$ measurable. What I am unsure is how to prove that $E1_{Y^{-1}(A)}g(X,Y)=\int_\Omega[1_{Y^{-1}(A)}(\omega)\int_Rg(x,Y(\omega)) P_{X|Y}(dx,\omega)]P(d\omega)$ for all Borel $A$. Is there some resource with the proof of (1)?
I first tried to approach this problem by seeing if it holds for some non-negative simple function $g(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i1_{A_{i}}(x,y)$.I obtain:
$$E1_{Y^{-1}(A)}g(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^na_iP(\{(X,Y)\in A_i\}\cap\{Y\in A\})$$
The problem is that I dont know how to express $P(\{(X,Y)\in A_i\}\cap\{Y\in A\})$ in terms of some integral of the regular conditional distribution $P_{X|Y}$.

Instead of using $A_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, you can look at sets of the form $B_i \times C_i$ for $B_i,C_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Borel. These form a $\pi$-system generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$ so it is enough to work on this special case.
